# Wordpress not cropping thumbnails correctly only at grid page

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, crop

Somehow wordpress isn't cropping my thumbnails correctly at my grid page.

The actual images have this size: **984 x 1202 Pixel**.
I set this size in my dashboard and in the `functions.php`

```
function tws_adoxa_theme_setup() {    

...

add_image_size( 'tws-adoxa-grid-thumbnail', 984, 1202, true );
add_image_size( 'tws-adoxa-list-thumbnail', 984, 1202, true );

...

}
```

But somehow the images are cropped to 324 x 341 Pixel and I don't know where this sizes comes from...

https://duni-cheri.de/category/blog/

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry - it somehow fixed itself and I don't know why... but ok.